# installing a python package not supported by pip or conda into Anaconda on Windows

Tags: python, package, anaconda

I have a python package i would like to install or link into Anaconda.

I currently have the package, `http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pythtb/install.html`, running by setting up both stock python and Anaconda separately on my Windows machine. (I can only run the desired package in stock python)  Ideally, I would like to use the package in Anaconda.

The package i installed came in as an exe file and all i needed to be able to use it in stock python was just to run the exe file.

i have done some googling and found `python setup.py install` as a way to do just that ( from `https://python4astronomers.github.io/installation/packages.html`)

It made very little sense to me (im not sure if it's even applicable to my case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you have 64 bit python
2. Make sure that the version of `python` when you type `C:\> python` is the one you want, e.g it is from Anaconda
3. Make sure you have numpy & matplotlib installed for this python
4. Download [pythtb-1.6.2.zip](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pythtb/_downloads/pythtb-1.6.2.zip) to your working directory
5. Unzip it in this directory, you should see a `setup.py` there
6. run `python setup.py install`

Alternately, with the [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel/) package installed, one can run `wheel convert pythtb-1.6.2.exe` on a wininst exe installer to convert it into a wheel that is installable by pip.